# clock implementation using forever in verilog

Tags: verilog, hardware

I am implementing a sequential circuit in verilog . I want a clock of time period 10 . For implementing that I have done something like

```
 initial begin
       forever begin
            clk=0;
            #5
            clk=1;
            #5
            clk=0;
       end
   end
```

But when I run the code , it keeps on running without showing any output. Is there any error in above implementation?

Comment: It depends very much on the rest of your code. Do you ever call `$finish`? If not, there is always more to do as the `forever` block will keep scheduling event for the `clk` to change value. (Note that you can do it much simpler with `initial begin clk = 0; forever clk = #5 ~clk; end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code keeps on running since there is no $finish. So it's a free running oscillator.

Following are some of the methods for clock generation. More or less, they all are same.

Method 1 :

```
        parameter int clk_tgl_period = 5;
        parameter timeout = 500;    
        module clkgen1;
        reg clk;
        initial begin
            clk <= '0;
            forever #(clk_tgl_period) clk = ~clk;
        end
        initial begin
            #(timeout) $finish
        end
        endmodule
```

Method - 2

```
        parameter int clk_tgl_period = 5;
        parameter timeout = 500;    
        module clkgen2;
        reg clk;
        initial begin 
            clk = 0;
            #(timeout) $finish;
        end
        always #(clk_tgl_period) clk = ~clk;
        endmodule
```

Method - 3

```
        parameter int clk_tgl_period = 5;
        parameter timeout = 500;    
        module clkgen3;
        reg clk;
        initial begin
            clk = 0;
            #(timeout) $finish;
        end
        always #(clk_tgl_period) clk++;
        endmodule
```

For more information, you may want to have a look at **Section-4** of [CummingsSNUG2006Boston_SystemVerilog_Events Paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2006Boston_SystemVerilog_Events.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

One way of implementing it is as follows (assuming you are using this in a testbench):

```
parameter clock_period=10;

always 
#(clock_period/2) clock=~clock;

initial begin
clock=0;
 #1000 $finish; // You can put the delay as per your requirement.
end
```